# Getting around forbidden when web scraping

Tags: python, http

I am trying to make a discord bot to print a single integer when the command is called. This is my current attempt, and I know that I am missing something vital.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
site = "site"

def getInfo():
    hdr = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    req = Request(site,headers=hdr)
    page = urlopen(req)
    response = requests.get(site)
    soup = BeautifulSoup('span', 'html.parser')



getInfo()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix ='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("Prefix is !")
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def pcount(ctx):
    await bot.say(getInfo())


bot.run("Key")
```

I am pretty sure that a bunch of my imports are redundant, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. I am pretty new to python, and this is my second real project with it.

The current issue is that nothing prints into discord the following reason. I call the !pcount command, and this is the error.

```
Ignoring exception in command pcount
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 28, in pcount
    await bot.say(getInfo())
  File "C:\Users\Zane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 309, in _augmented_msg
    msg = yield from coro
  File "C:\Users\Zane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 1152, in send_message
    data = yield from self.http.send_message(channel_id, content, guild_id=guild_id, tts=tts, embed=embed)
  File "C:\Users\Zane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 200, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400): Cannot send an empty message

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Zane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 374, in invoke
    yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Zane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 54, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400): Cannot send an empty message
```

I know the error is because Discord has a filter against bots sending messages with no contents, but I am not sure how to read a response object for example into something that I want, and for this project I want a single variable from the website.

Comment: It's not completely clear what is the problem - please elaborate what is happening, and what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I got around the issue just by using requests, and using BS to parse the HTML data. Here's what I have.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
site = "SITE URL"

def open():
    #headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}

    rec = requests.get(site)
    soupPage = soup(rec.text, "html.parser")
    players = soupPage.find("span", {"id" : "HTML_num_players"})
    #print(players)
    playersString = str(players)
    playersEdit = playersString.strip('<span id="HTML_num_players">/')
    #print (playersEdit)
    return playersEdit






bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix ='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("Prefix is !, jackass")
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def playercount(ctx):
    await bot.say("Current playercount is " + open())
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def pc(ctx):
    await bot.say("Current playercount is " + open())




bot.run("KEY")
```